# Relation between two different definitions of deficiency of a graph.

Tags: graph-theory

From Lovasz's Matching Theory,

> Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with
>   bipartition $(A, B)$. For $X \subset
> > A$, define $def(X) :=|X|-|\Gamma(X)|$, where $\Gamma(Χ)$
>   denote all points in $V(G)$ which are
>   adjacent to at least one point of $X$.
>   $def(G) := \max_{X \subset A}
> > def(X)$ will be called the
>   $Α$-deficiency of $G$. If $A$ is
>   understood, we shall simply call this
>   number the deficiency of G.
>
> Let $G$ be a graph not necessarily
>   bipartite. Define $def'(X) :=odd(G-X) - |X|$, and the deficiency of the graph
>   is defined as $def'(G) := \max_{X
>  \subset V(G)} def'(X)$.

In a bipartite graph, these are two different concepts unfortunately with the same name in the book. From [Tutte-Berge Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte-Berge_formula), and THEOREM 1.3.1 in the book, which states

> The matching number of a bipartite
>   graph G is $|A|-def(G)$.

I derive that $def'(G) = |B| - |A| + 2 def(G).$ I wonder how to prove/explain this relation between the two deficiencies more directly based on their definitions?

Is there some definite relation  between $def(X)$ and $def'(X)$ for a subset $X$ of $A$?

Thanks!